# I am unable to install anything from terminal in ubuntu 16.10

Tags: dual-boot, 16.10

Sometimes it show unable to locate pakage otherwise it show unable to fetch some archives.
If I try sudo apt-get update
Then also same errors showing- unable to fetch

Also this error-
The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety Release' does no longer have a Release file.

So many errors realted to repository is show.
Please suggest the solutions?
I really need your help.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the following link:

[Ubutnu Roadmap](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

the Ubuntu **16.10** has reached *End of Life*, meaning that it is no supported anymore and that is the reason that you don't see any updates.

The best you can do is to install a recent version. Either you pick Ubuntu **16.04** LTS with 5 years of support, or pick Ubuntu **17.10** with 9 months of support.